# How to stop SQL Server or take event based custom action using Extended Events feature

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, extended-events

This is regarding SQL Server `Extended Events` feature which got introduced with SQL Server 2008 and got a GUI interface in version 2012. In specific to its so many wonderful features I also read it [here](http://logicalread.solarwinds.com/why-use-sql-server-extended-events-w01/#.V7_mVfl97mg) that you can also stop the SQL Server when you encounter a specific event during an extended event capture session. I searched a bit about it but I'm unable to get any leads as to **how to take any such custom action e.g. stopping the SQL Server based on the occurrence of an event e.g. `lock_deadlock`**.

I went through all the tabs in properties window as shown below after creating the extended event session using new session wizard but I'm unable to get anything like that where I can configure such condition based actions.

[image]

It will be really great if someone has used it and can guide me appropriately on this.

Answer (score 0):

Hello In MSSQL @Verison 2008 not supported this Views  So some developers make SQL addin,
I prefer **extendedeventmanager** addin.

[Dowland extendedeventmanager](https://extendedeventmanager.codeplex.com)

Thanks